# how to install and configure postgresql and django in the same dockerfile

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I need to install and configure postgresql and django in one container, I can't use docker-compose because the hosting doesn't have support for docker-compose.

i try of following in dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

USER postgres

RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'postgres';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker


RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf


RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port

EXPOSE 5432

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]


CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]



FROM python

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app/roche

COPY requirements.txt /app/roche

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/roche



CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

but I get this error

[image]

This is my configure postgres in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'docker',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

this is the link of the answer why I can't use more than one container in plesk

https://talk.plesk.com/threads/networking-between-docker-containers.353312/

thanks to all who read and respond

Comment: The second [FROM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) creates a new [build stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds); you can copy data between the stages but "intermediate artifacts are left behind, and not saved in the final image" (so your final image does not contain PostgreSQL). Is there a reason that you need a single container (rather than one for PostgreSQL and one for your application - you don't need `docker-compose` to accomplish this).

Comment: Please [don't upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of code/errors when asking a question (paste the text and format as code)

Comment: hi bro tanks for the answer , in hosting (plesk) there is no way to connect two containers

Comment: "there is no way to connect two containers" in what way? (I'm not familiar with plesk but would expect it to be possible to expose Postgres via the host interface). You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225387/how-to-run-the-python-application-and-postgres-in-one-docker-container) helpful.

Comment: The Docker documentation even includes a [Django, PostgreSQL, and Docker Compose sample](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/).  But as @Brits notes, the inputs to these are textual YAML files and not images.  Can you edit the question to include the information needed to reproduce the issue (in a form that someone could copy and run locally if necessary, or search for later)?

Comment: @Brits  Thanks friends if this question helps me, thank you very much for your time, and look at this link https://talk.plesk.com/threads/networking-between-docker-containers.353312/ , here they answer because you cannot use plesk with two connectors, it is a real shit hahahaha, 
I already update the answer with code

Comment: @DavidMaze 
I already update the answer with code, tanks my friend you are the best

Comment: So am I right in thinking that you are doing this through the "Docker extension" and don't have command line access to the VM? The post you linked to is correct that you cannot use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` within a container to reference the host but docker provides [dns](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) to enable you to locate other containers (and options for retrieving the hosts address).

Comment: @Brits yes brother, what you say is correct i have to use docker extension but i don't understand  , i  don't know how to use this ("dns") to make it work for me